# Receiving HTTP_DATA_ERROR: timeout when using Android Download Manager

Tags: java, android, timeout, android-download-manager

I'm initiating a download request using the Android Download Manager for JSON data via a web service and most of the responses come back successfully and save the response to disk. But some requests are never returning a successful response. When I check the device logs I see

DownloadManager: [162] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: timeout

I can load the URL in my browser and get the JSON response, but it does take several seconds to be returned. Is there a way to increase the timeout in the DownloadManager or another work around?

Comment: "Is there a way to increase the timeout in the DownloadManager" -- I don't think so. "or another work around?" -- download it yourself, using an HTTP API (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CommonsWare. I'd really prefer not to have to re-architect the app since it was built to use the DownloadManager, but good to know there is another option if I have to change it out.

Comment: @Austin i know it has been 5 years since then, but where you able to increase the timeout for DownloadManger I'm facing the same issue.